# Confusing C program output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
int i=2;
i=i---i--;
printf("%d",i);
getch();
}
```

I don't understand why output of this program is 1. I guess it may be precedence of operators. but I don't figure out why this.

Comment: Modifying the same variable twice between sequence points is undefined. Don't do it.

Comment: Apart from the fairly obvious undefined behavior, `i=i---i--;` is tokenized, via the "maximal munch" rule, as `i = i -- - i -- ;`.

Comment: conio and getch? Seriously? Upgrade your compiler!

Comment: What are your trying to achieve with this instruction (i=i---i--;).

Comment: Whenever you see some weird structure like `i=i---i--;`, remember it doesn't do what you intuitively think it does.

Comment: @Barmar if it is undefined then why the program giving output and why the output is 1.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means the program can do anything. That includes giving output.

Comment: @paxdiablo which compiler do you ?????

Comment: @Barmar that's wrong dude this program not showing different thing every time i run this but gives a definite answer. so if you know why this answer is then help me ?

Comment: Why would it show different output? "undefined" doesn't mean that it changes, it just means that the language doesn't specify what should happen.

Comment: It's not likely to differ with a particular implementation, but it may give a different answer with different implementations.

Comment: @Barmar bro you say language doesn't specify why this output is coming. then what the rule which specify this output.

Comment: There is no "rule", it's whatever the implementor happened to decide to do.